# Installing CouchDB on IaaS?

Tags: cloud, couchdb, centos6, iaas, dbaas

After many many google searches I am still unclear on how to install a CouchDB instance on an Infrastructure as a Service cloud service. I have looked into DBaaS options such as Cloudant, but for initial testing I would like to host the database on an IaaS.

Specifically, I am wanting to host my database on [Nifty Cloud](http://cloud.nifty.com/), a Japan-only IaaS. Is this even possible?

I can use Windows or CentOS Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get SSH credentials for your booked IaaS OS e.g. CentOS
2. Login
3. Create a CouchDB user
4. Download the CouchDB sources
5. Build the sources
6. Set access and execution rights
7. Configure the `local.ini`
8. Start the CouchDB
9. visit the Futon admin page under `yourip:port/_utils`

You find a step-by-step description for several OS's in the CouchDB installation notes.